# Access to Proxy Protocol address within HAProxy

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, tcp, haproxy, http-headers

I am running HAProxy that is receiving layer 4 proxy protocol from an upstream source. I have a need to create a custom HTTP header with the address contained there. I can't seem to find how I can reference that TCP header.

Below is a sample of what I am trying to do:

```
frontend http_in
    bind *:1025 accept-proxy
    mode http
    default_backend http_out

backend http_out
    mode http
    http-request set-header X-Custom-Header %[<ip from proxy protocol header>]
    server some-server some-server:80
```

How can I make sure I am populating the new header with the address from the L4 header and not some spoofable http header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [docs](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#5.1-accept-proxy) of the `accept-proxy` bind option, and more generically the usage of the PROXY protocol, all the fields contained in the PROXY protocol header (source IP & port, destination IP & port) replace those from the real connection:

> ...
>   The PROXY protocol dictates the layer 3/4 addresses of the incoming
>   connection to be used everywhere an address is used, with the only
>   exception of "tcp-request connection" rules which will only see the
>   real connection address. Logs will reflect the addresses indicated in
>   the protocol, unless it is violated, in which case the real address
>   will still be used.
>   ...

Meaning that your backend would look like

```
backend http_out
    mode http
    http-request set-header X-Custom-Header %[src]
    server some-server some-server:80
```

This works because the `src` sample field will contain the source IP as defined in the PROXY header, and not the actual source IP.